# Linux as a hidden operating system in Truecrypt?

Tags: linux, encryption, truecrypt

I know, for example, that you cannot encrypt a system partition with Linux on it, only with Windows, if you have only one OS. But I wonder if you can use the "Hidden OS" feature and make Windows your outer system and Linux your hidden system - is that possible?

Comment: What makes you think you cannot encrypt a system partition if you are using Linux?  You really shouldn't use the last version of TrueCrypt capable of encrypting, it has problems, large enough to warrant not using it.

Comment: Completely agree with @Ramhound on most, but I would like to see a source on the supposed vulnerabilities. per the AuditTruecrypt project, no serious problems were found. https://www.grc.com/misc/truecrypt/truecrypt.htm

Comment: There's no "Encrypt the system partition or entire system drive" in the Linux version of Truecrypt but there is in Windows. Check this yourself. There's no such option in the Linux version of Veracrypt too.

Comment: There were multiple rounds and those findings all have been published, the forks that exist, have fixed all the minor and major vulnerabilities, some of those are just weakness in the key size/strength most are not exploitable.  Of course the use of any fork means no Secure Boot in any OS, which has saved many people from, newer malware on Windows and Linux that go after MBR installations

Comment: Ok but that was not the subject of the question. You haven't addressed my comment which says that you can't encrypt the system partition if using Linux but you say you can.

Answer (score 1):

Linux has it's own encryption, (of course) not using truecrypt.

It *usually* requires an unencrypted boot partition, but you could store that on a removable disk or USB drive...

It also *usually* uses a LUKS partition, which is not hidden (the LUKS header is easily seen).

For all the *usual* behaviour, it can be customized to do whatever you want, though it's not nearly as easy as just clicking an "Encrypt my system" checkbox in an installer like Linux Mint or Ubuntu have.

Using plain dm-crypt (instead of LUKS) would have a more "hidden" partition, with no easily visible header, but more config info and less passphrase strengthening (no multiple passphrases either) than LUKS provides.

- [ArchLinux's wiki/help pages have **excellent information** on all the generally available **encryption** for Linux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Disk_encryption) - Read it!

---

For a solution to your "hidden linux inside windows", you could try **keeping a virtual machine** (like VirtualBox or VMWare?) installation running Linux, all **on a hidden encrypted partition** (or large file) that you decrypt & run from inside windows. There are lots of signs that windows leaves behind indicating that programs have been running, so a *portable* VM that's not actually installed would help some...

Answer (score 1):

Hidden Linux OS howto in simple steps, but hard to get it work, it is working in a test i had done, no clue hidden os is there.

Needs: know how to inject full linux losetup (one with -P and --offset and --sizelimit parameters) into initrams with hooks directory, etc.

Steps:

Install a Linux on a 100% encrypted HDD, use Grub2 to let it boot from encrypted rootfs with /boot as folder.
Locate a large block list non used on rootfs partition.
Create a loop on fly-decrypted rootfs, but not over a file, over the luks, need to do losetup with --offset and --sizelimit, since offset and size are "secret" (only stored on your mind, not on grub.cfg).

In detail, how it works is simply to explain, from a new HDD with no data on it:

Create a GPT table, with only one partition, encrypt with LUKS such partition, install a dummy Linux on it with grug2 as bootloader (do not forget to add --modules="luks" when doing grub2-install, so grub2 can be intalled inside luks partition, no need for /boot as partition, it can be a folder inside encrypted LUKS rootfs)... this Linux will be the one seen by forensic tools, border agents, etc.

Now locate a non-used secuential area on free space (beware not to overwrite such area when using external Linux), that secuential blocks will be used for a hidden os.

Create a loop with losetup --ofset=InitialPosition --sizelimit=SizeOfSuchSpace on the decrypted luks (/dev/mapper/...), this loop will be seen as a virtual hdd stored over free space... (this is the same concept that TrueCrypt and VeraCrypt use).

Create a LUKS (without header) so you have a new /dev/mapper/... for such space, inside that one create a ext4 or a full GPT table with partitions scheme you want for real hidden OS, install the Linux you want (same 32 or 64 bits as external one, but not need to be same distro, only same architecture), but before reboot, edit initram scripts to and the full losetup ans libraries needed (the one standard on initramfs does not support --offset and --sizelimit, it only support from X position to end of block device), put also scripts to mount external rootfs (where some blocks are used for hidden os), then on such script also add the losetup command (use personal parameters for telling from grub2 the offset and sizelimit or hard code them on the script), that will create a device /dev/loop# for such blocks, put the command to open the LUKS (with no luks header), that will create a /dev/mapper/... as a block device, then mount the filesystem or do another losetup with -P parameter if you create partitions scheme, etc (if you create partitions on such luks the use -P parameter on losetup will create /dev/loop#p# devices, so need to add mount commands for such loops), now hidden os is accesible (remember to mount rotfs over /root folder)... all this command goes on a pre-mount script for the initramfs.

How will extenal visible OS will boot: Power on, BIOS or [U]EFI loads, Grub2 is loaded from inside LUKS encrypted partition with /boot as folder, it asks for passphase for such luks (that is why --modules="luks" is needed when installing grub2), then menu appears, select to boot Linux and external Linux will be loaded from such rootfs that is encrypted by luks... inside that rootfs you will have a lot of contiguos free blocks since it will have a lot of free space, some of them are the ones that only your mind knows are used for some data (really not free, but linux filesystem have them as frre), such datanwill be the hidden os, so no one can demostrate the is something.

Why not possible so detect such space as different from the rest? Because the data stored there is encrypted by same luks as the external Linux, but when decrypted by such luks, it will be seen as andom data since it is also encrypted by another luks layer (beware that one must be wity no luks header, this is a must, or else it would be detectable).

Now how to boot onto hidden os: Power on, BIOS or [U]EFI loads, Grub2 is loaded from inside LUKS encrypted partition with /boot as folder, it asks for passphase for such external luks (that is why --modules="luks" is needed when installing grub2), then menu appear, press 'c' key to go to console and start typing grub2 commands to get access to hidden os, this will asks for hidden os passphrase, then command to load vmlinuz... with personal parameters for offset and sizelimit (if not hard coded on initram scripts), then type boot to start booting the hidden os, it will ask again for both passphrases while booting (for the external and for the hidden).

Commands on grub2 (not exact only a guide): 
insmod luks (maybe not needed, it is to able to call cryptmount)
cryptmount (hd0,gpt1), to mount external luks thar resides on /dev/sda1
loopback my_loop (crypto0), with offset and sizelimit parameters (data that is only on your mind)
cryptmount (my_loop), to mount the rootfs of the hidden os
linux (crypto1,gpt1)/boot/vmlinuz... my_parameter_offset=value my_param_size=value
initrd (crypto1,gpt1)/boot/initrd.img...
boot

Adapt values to your specific scenario, gpt is for gpt partition tables, for bios one it is msdos (hd0,msdos1) or just number (hd0,1), etc.

Some distros create a symbolic link to /boot/vmlinuz... on /vmlinuz and same idea for /boot/initrd.img... to /initrd.img so easier to update since no need to remember names for such files.

This works as a perfect plausible denay, because it is impossible for any forensic to determine what blocks are used for the hidden os and which ones have random data. All of them are encrypted by same luks layer (the external), if external passphrase must be revealed, all hidden os blocks appear as free non-used blocks on such filesystem, and the data seen can not be detected as nothing else than random data. The start possition and length is not stored anywhere (only on your mind) and since hidden os is inside a luks (with no luks header) there is no way to see there is another luks anywhere on the decrypted external luks.

That grub2 commands to boot hidden os must not be stored anywhere except your mind, or else the hidden os would be able to be seen.

I know it is hard to boot it that way, but it is the first full 100% working i got to work.

Problem: If external os is used, after hidden os is present, the hidden os can get damaged, since its blocks are seen as free on such external Linux, so it can overwrite them. But at least, your private data stay private and with plausible denay it is present.

There is no way to detect such hidden os without knowing all this:
-External passphrase
-Initial position of blocks used for hidden os
-Size (number of blocks) for hidden os
-Hidden OS passphrase

Very important:
-Hidden os blocks must be on free space of decrypted external luks, not a file on such filesystem.
-Hidden os block must be a only one contiguos region
-External os can damage hidden os if used

Tip: how to get a full contiguos block area... with a livecd first create a low level block clone of external linux (the real hdd, encrypted), so you can restore it after, i recommend to clone to a file... the mount the file as a loop and open the luks, create a big file, get file block list, ensure it is contiguos, now you have start and size for hidden os... unmount luks and loop for the file, delete the file... now you know that on real hdd, after open luks you know a whole area of free blocks you can use for hidden os.

I hope someone with real big knonledge could implement all this under a two passphrase bifurcation (if passphrase1 use only go to external linux, if paassphrase2 go to hidden one).

TrueCrypt and VeraCryrpt can not ensure denay, since they know how to access hidden os without user telling it where hidden os is... no matter how it stores that info, the info is there... so this Linux solution is better in terms of security, but too much hard to use on day use, imagine need to boot five times per day.

I do not know of other method to really have a hidden linux, neither i know of any one knowing it.

Very Important, really very important: To be able to boot into hidden os, you need (at least) grub2 version 2.02~beta3 (yes beta3, not beta2, since beta2 has a big bug with cryptomount command since it only allows one call to it, the rest does nothing, and it also do not let access to unencrypted luks).

Hope more people use this structure for hidden os. I use it on all my Linux (32 and 64 bits ones).

Estimated time to implement: More then one/two days.
Level of knonledge: Very high, really very high.
Speed of hidden OS: Less than 15MiB/s read/write on an old Pentium IV HT (3.4GHz), much faster on modern PCs and much more if encryption procesor hardware instructions are used... you are using two layers in cascade, some loops, etc.